# Code allowing only text to be entered in a text box and displaying "error" in a msgbox if a number or other character is entered

Tags: vb.net-2010

Code allowing only text to be entered in a text box and displaying "error" in a msgbox if a number or other character is entered

Here's my code:

```vb
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    NA = Val(TextBox1.Text)
    If NA > 0 Then
        MsgBox("Error")
    Else
        NA = Val(TextBox1.Text)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: A little bit more context would have been nice, for example what you've tried to do so far, and whether this is a Forms application or an ASP application, as that can affect the answer.

Comment: You want to display an error an a number or another character is entered, so the user just enter an invalid char and get the error, or you want to validate when the TextBox losses its focus? I presume the last option?

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm not sure if this is in a Forms application or an ASP application, you might want to look at the [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) class:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions   

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

       If Regex.Match(TextBox1.Text, @"\d")
           MsgBox("Error")               
       Else
           NA = Val(TextBox1.Text)
       End If

End Sub
```

If you're using ASP, you could take a look at [Control Validators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx), they're built into .Net, can be added and configured from the page designer, and inject all the necessary components into your page based on your requirements. I haven't used them in quite a long time, so I'm afraid I can't provide any specific details.

Comment: A little more information than "regex is not working" is always nice. I haven't used these in a while, but check out control validators - they're build into .Net and can be added and configured from the page designer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx